# Does Firebase charge you for just updating fields in Cloud Firestore?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Base on the Firebase Billing system they are only charging for read, writes and deletes in Cloud Firestore. Do they charge for just updating a field in a document in Firestore?

Comment: Creating, updating and deleting are all writes.

Comment: @danh oh I see.

Answer (score 1):

According to this [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/pricing#operations):

> Charges for writes and deletes are straightforward. For writes, each
> `set` or `update` operation counts as a single write.

Just to add, if you're `update` or `set` has failed then you're not charged as there's not any document change.